# Ruby method-calling hierarchy

Tags: ruby

Inspired by this [article](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/030-issue-1-method-lookup.html), I was playing around with the Ruby method calling hierarchy and noticed something strange.

Given:

```
class B
  def foo  
    "- Instance method defined by B"
  end  

  def method_missing(method)
    puts "- method_missing (#{method}) on b. Redirecting to b.foo\n"
    foo
  end
end

b = B.new

def b.foo  
  "- Method defined directly on an instance of B\n" + super  
end

def b.method_missing(method)
  "- method_missing (#{method}) on b. Calling super\n" + super
end

puts "Calling 'bar' on b of type #{b.class}:"
puts b.bar
```

Running it gives:

```
Calling 'bar' on b of type B:
- method_missing (bar) on b. Redeirecting to b.foo
- method_missing (bar) on b. Calling super
- Method defined directly on an instance of B
- instance method defined by B
```

My question is:

Since I am calling b.bar (on the object), how come the class's instance method is called before the objet's instance method is called?

I would have expected `b.method_missing(method)` to be called first, then the class's instance `method_missing(method)` (since I am calling super? but super is class hierarchy...) which the does the redirect from `bar` to `foo`.
Also, how come, after being redirected to `foo`, the instance's missing_method is called? We were just told that we're being redirected...

I think I don't understand the concept of how Ruby allows to define an instance method on an instance of a class (new to me), as opposed to defining it as an instance method of a the class (classic languages).

I hope this question makes sense, maybe my head is still spinning from last night...

Comment: I removed irrelevant code to make the problem more apparent. It's generally a good idea to provide a *minimal* example of a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your output does not reflect the actual order of execution. Let's take a look at the output:

```
method_missing (bar) on b. Redeirecting to b.foo
method_missing (bar) on b. Calling super
```

At first glance, this gives the impression that `B#method_missing` is called before the singleton method `b.method_missing` which raises the two questions you describe. Actually though, `b.method_missing` is correctly called first. This gets clear if you look at how the statement `puts b.bar` is evaluated:

1. `b` has no method `bar`, so `b.method_missing` is called with the string `'bar'` as an argument.
2. `b.method_missing` in turn calls the method `B#method_missing` through use of the `super` keyword.
3. `B#method_missing` uses `puts` to output the first line seen above
4. the singleton method `b.foo` is called
5. the outermost `puts` is performed, which outputs the string in `b.method_missing` along with the return value of `b.foo`

Comment: Niklas, thanks for clarifying (and removing the irrelevant code). Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Running it in the debugger of course clarifies it. I should have done that to start with - sorry guys, and thanks for your patience.